# Five languages to account for

Tags: connect-wall

Here's another connect wall, with the usual goal of putting four words into Group One, another four words into Group Two, four more into Group Three, and four into Group Four. This puzzle is also misleading—at first it looks like it's just grouping the words by language, but the number of languages is too big and the number of words in each language too small. What's going on, do you reckon?

Hint:

> The languages do ultimately matter, but the meanings of the words don't matter….

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| avfyra | chiquilicuatro | detta | едва |
| entzweien | Erdreich | Klavier | kortvåg |
| lagunosa | megkettőzés | megye | острие |
| родина | sastresa | strejk | vonósnégyes |

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*What's going on, do you reckon?*

> It's right there in the question: *"the number of languages"*. Each non-English word contains, as a substring, a numeral in the same language.

*Group One*

> d**ett**a, Swedish, **ett**, one
>  lag**uno**sa, Spanish, **uno**, one
>  m**egy**e, Hungarian, **egy**, one
>  р**один**а, Russian, **один**, one

*Group Two*

> е**два**, Russian, **два**, two
>  ent**zwei**en, German, **zwei**, two
>  kor**två**g, Swedish, **två**, two
>  meg**kettő**zés, Hungarian, **kettő**, two

*Group Three*

> Er**drei**ch, German, **drei**, three
>  ос**три**е, Russian, **три**, three
>  sas**tres**a, Spanish, **tres**, three
>  s**tre**jk, Swedish, **tre**, three

*Group Four*

> av**fyra**, Swedish, **fyra**, four
>  chiquili**cuatro**, Spanish, **cuatro**, four
>  Kla**vier**, German, **vier**, four
>  vonós**négy**es, Hungarian, **négy**, four

Comment: So stupid of me to not find the hidden word in "chiquilicuatro"

Comment: Beautifully done!